# Making Thread wait until a time at next day

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety

I have a thread and I want it to wait until a specific time next day. 
What is the best way achieving this?

I tried two alternatives :

1.

```
var restTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(hour).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
Thread.Sleep(restTime);
```

2.

```
var restTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(hour).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, restTime);
```

Comment: So do you want to keep your CPU running at 100% for the entirety of that time you're waiting?

Comment: No, actually I do not want to affect other processes.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis yes, only difference is my thread will wait 20+ hours.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it this way. Use a library like [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) and schedule a task to be executed at a specific date and time. There's no point in creating a thread only to have it not performing work for a long time.

Comment: Or just use the built-in Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Yep, going out-of-process is always an option, although the Windows Task Scheduler comes with its own headaches--configuration, security and it still has to actually run an executable. With Quartz.NET, the OP could just run his existing task without much modification to his program.

Answer (score 1):

SpinWait is a BIG NO NO! With spingwait your thread won't give up its turn and will keep consuming resources.

I'd go with system timer and let that notify my function at specified time in comparsion to sleep and then check again

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Timer for this case.

```
var intervalTime= DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(hour).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
Timer stateTimer = new Timer(
timerDelegate, autoEvent, delayTime, intervalTime);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch%28v=vs.100%29.aspx